# SlickJS, unslick() remove issue

Tags: jquery, window-resize

Good Afternoon,

I'm currently working and using [SlickJS Carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), I'm trying to remove several items when the window width is larger than 375 using the `unslick();` snippet.

I can see the resize function working as when the window size is less than 375 the `slick();` carousel display without any issues.

If anyone can see whats going wrong please let me know.

Thank you.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Header Slider 
    $('.touchslider_one').slick({
        autoplay: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 1500,
        autoplaySpeed: 3000,
        dots: false,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        fade: true,
        cssEase: 'linear',
    });
    onresize();
    $(window).resize(function () {
        onresize();
    });
});
function onresize(){
    checkWidth();
}
function checkWidth() {
    if ($(window).width() < 376 ) {
        // Boxes
        $('.touchslider_fourth').slick({
            autoplay: false,
            infinite: true,
            speed: 1500,
            adaptiveHeight: true,
            dots: false,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            cssEase: 'linear'
        });
        // Featured Products
        $('.touchslider_three').slick({
            autoplay: false,
            infinite: true,
            speed: 1500,
            adaptiveHeight: true,
            dots: false,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            cssEase: 'linear'
        });
        // Logos 
        $('.touchslider_two').unslick();
        $('.touchslider_two').slick({
            autoplay: true,
            infinite: true,
            speed: 1500,
            autoplaySpeed: 6000,
            dots: false,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            cssEase: 'linear'
        });
    } else {
        // Test
        console.log('Larger than 375');             

        // Remove
        $('.touchslider_fourth').unslick();
        $('.touchslider_three').unslick();
        $('.touchslider_two').unslick();
        // Rebuild
        $('.touchslider_two').slick({
            autoplay: true,
            infinite: true,
            speed: 1500,
            autoplaySpeed: 6000,
            dots: false,
            slidesToShow: 5,
            slidesToScroll: 5,
            cssEase: 'linear'
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 28):

Try this:

```
$('.your-slider').slick('unslick');
```

Comment: for whatever reason, this works for me whereas '$element.unslick()' doesn't

Answer (score 6):

After talking with [Ken Wheeler](https://github.com/kenwheeler) and reading through a couple [Github](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/369) issues it looked like [wtran](https://github.com/wtran) had the answer I was looking for, Although I had to tweak to match my requirements it pretty much worked first time around.

I'm now able to trigger `unslick();` when the window resizes over a specific width and rebuild the carousel if the window resizes less than the specific width.

I would also like to thank [Ken Wheeler](https://github.com/kenwheeler) for the Tweets and advice!

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    touchsliderone();
    onresize();
    $(window).resize(function () {
        onresize();
    });
});
// Resize 
function onresize () {
    touchslidertwo();
    touchsliderthree();
    touchsliderfour();
}
// Header Carousel
function touchsliderone() {
    $('.touchslider_one').slick({
        autoplay: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 1500,
        autoplaySpeed: 3000,
        dots: false,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        fade: true,
        cssEase: 'linear',
    });
}
// Boxes Carousel
function touchsliderfour() {
 var $touchsliderfour = $('.touchslider_four');
    if ($(window).width() < 376) {
      if($touchsliderfour.hasClass('slick-initialized')) {
        $touchsliderfour.unslick();
      }
        $touchsliderfour.slick({
            autoplay: false,
            infinite: true,
            speed: 1500,
            adaptiveHeight: true,
            dots: false,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            cssEase: 'linear'
        });
    } else {
      if($touchsliderfour.hasClass('slick-initialized')) {
        $touchsliderfour.unslick();
      }
    }
}
// Featured Products Carousel
function touchsliderthree() {
    var $touchsliderthree = $('.touchslider_three');
    if ($(window).width() < 376) {
      if($touchsliderthree.hasClass('slick-initialized')) {
        $touchsliderthree.unslick();
      }
        $touchsliderthree.slick({
            autoplay: false,
            infinite: true,
            speed: 1500,
            adaptiveHeight: true,
            dots: false,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            cssEase: 'linear'
        });
    } else {
      if($touchsliderthree.hasClass('slick-initialized')) {
        $touchsliderthree.unslick();
      }
    }
}
// Logos Carousel 
function touchslidertwo() {
    var $touchslidertwo = $('.touchslider_two');
    if ($(window).width() < 376) {
      if($touchslidertwo.hasClass('slick-initialized')) {
        $touchslidertwo.unslick();
      }
        $touchslidertwo.slick({
            autoplay: true,
            infinite: true,
            speed: 1500,
            autoplaySpeed: 6000,
            dots: false,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            cssEase: 'linear'
        });
    } else {
      if($touchslidertwo.hasClass('slick-initialized')) {
        $touchslidertwo.unslick();
      }
        $touchslidertwo.slick({
            autoplay: true,
            infinite: true,
            speed: 1500,
            autoplaySpeed: 6000,
            dots: false,
            slidesToShow: 5,
            slidesToScroll: 5,
            cssEase: 'linear'
        });
    }
}
```