# unslick method not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, slick.js

I am trying to work out why the unslick method isn't working when I am calling it after a successful ajax call. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27276119/slickjs-unslick-remove-issue) post and am looking for the `slick-initialized` class, but I am still getting the error

> TypeError: *.$slides is null if (*.$slides.parent().hasClass('slick-track'))

HTML

```
<div id="skills" class="skills_section">
  <div>Slide 1</div>
  <div>Slide 2</div>
  <div>Slide 3</div>
</div>
```

When I initialize slick on page load the markup will look like this:

```
<div id="skills" class="skills_section slick-initialized slick-slider">
  <div class="slick-list draggable">
    <div class="slick-track">
      <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned">Slide 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I have an ajax call that will just replace the data in each `slick-slide`

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url: '/public/index',
  dataType: 'script',
  data: data_send,
   success: function(data) {
     unSlickCarousel();
     slickCarousel();
   }
});
```

Functions

```
function slickCarousel() {
  $('.skills_section').slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1
  });
}

function unSlickCarousel() {
  if($('#skills').hasClass('slick-initialized')){
    $('.skills_section').unslick();
  }
}
```

But as I have mentioned I get the error and the HTML markup looks like this

```
<div id="skills" class="skills_section slick-initialized slick-slider">
  <div>Slide 1</div>
  <div>Slide 2</div>
  <div>Slide 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1) I don't see what "I have read this post" is referring to. 2) In any case, I can't replicate your described issue with the code you've posted (http://jsfiddle.net/Palpatim/ezcot8o3/). Can you update with an MCVE? There could be some kind of interaction between the slick library and something else in your page, but we can't see it with what you've shown so far. You also mention "replacing data in each slide", but the code you've posted doesn't do so. Maybe that function is doing something to your structure?

Comment: thanks for taking the time to look into this and produce a js fiddle. well the data definitely changes (cant show you at the moment though). Ill have a closer look at what you have done and see if anything obvious presents itself

Answer (score 12):

I believe the way you call slick methods has changed.

Instead of `$('.skills_section').unslick();`

try `$('.skills_section').slick("unslick");`

You call also call this directly inside the responsive option in the slick options

Answer (score 3):

Use setTimeout for initialising slick()

```
function slickCarousel() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.skills_section').slick({
     infinite: true,
     slidesToShow: 3,
     slidesToScroll: 1
    });
  }, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen this error message before.

I'm going to assume the 3 instances of "slick-cloned" in your stackoverflow example is just a copy/paste error.
If you really have "slick-cloned" appearing all those times, there's your error.
the unslick() method needs to remove all "slick-cloned" slides as part of the process. 
If it removes all of your slides, then that's why slides is null.

Read line 627 on the actual js file to see that it does this:
https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/blob/master/slick/slick.js